# how to send data to web service from windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

I am building an application where i need to send data from a form to webservice on clicking the submit button.

My data will be stored in the webservice like this:

```
<UserDetails>
<id>29</id>
<name>Golkonda Gajanan</name>
<street_address>ponna </street_address>
<city_address>Ichoda  Adilabad </city_address>
<email_address>g17.golkonda@gmail.com</email_address>
<phone_no>9676101637</phone_no>
<zip_code>504307</zip_code>
<age>23</age>
<gender>Male</gender>
</UserDetails>
```

My xaml is

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus" Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,45,0,0"  Name="name"  Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
        <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus1" Height="118" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,108,0,0"  Name="saddress"  Text="Street Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
        <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus2" Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,213,0,0" Name="caddress" Text="City Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
        <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus3" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,319,0,0" Name="email" Text="Email Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
        <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus4" Height="76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,395,0,0" Name="phone" Text="Phone Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="281" />
        <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus5" Height="69" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,477,0,0" Name="zip" Text="Zip Code" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" />
        <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus6" Height="69" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,552,0,0" Name="age" Text="Age" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" />
        <RadioButton Content="Male" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,608,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" />
        <RadioButton Content="Female" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,608,0,0" Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" />
        <Button Content="Submit" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,672,0,0" Name="submit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" Click="submit_Click" />
        <Button Content="Reset" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,672,0,0" Name="reset" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" />
        <Button Content="Back" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="281,672,0,0" Name="back" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
    </Grid>
```

My cs file is

```
namespace KejriwalPhoneApp
{
    public partial class Join : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Join()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

    private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (name.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
        }

        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Data submitted successfully");
        }
    }


    private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (name.Text.Equals("Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            name.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (saddress.Text.Equals("Street Address", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            saddress.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (caddress.Text.Equals("City Address", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            caddress.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (email.Text.Equals("Email Address", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            email.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (phone.Text.Equals("Phone Number", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            phone.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (zip.Text.Equals("Zip Code", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            zip.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (age.Text.Equals("Age", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            age.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }


}
```

}

The web method is registertoteam

Comment: where is the service implementation? Have you created service proxy?

Comment: @EugeneP Yaa all those are done. I am able to get data in my device from webservice but i donot know how to send data from the app to webservice

Comment: the same way as you get data from service. Create method in the web service that accept parameter. Then from your WP7 app, call that method passing the data as method parameter.

Comment: @har07 please see my web method. see the new code that i have added

Comment: so it looks like simple asmx. could you post full service code. I can write code more close to real one.

Comment: @EugeneP should i post the .cs file or the asmx file?

Comment: @EugeneP please see the .cs code i posted just now

Comment: @user3156298 asmx. btw: have you added service reference to the wp7 project? or you are about to call service using webclient/etc

Comment: @EugeneP I would use service reference. I have done that for other pages but not for this till now

Comment: post an example showing how you call web service method to get data, and we can easily adept it to show how to call web service method to send data. or you already figured it out?

Comment: @har07 i havent done it yet. i am posting the way i call webservice method to get data

Comment: @har07 Please see the complete code i posted. I am not able to fix it. please help

Answer (score 1):

okay. so basically, all stuff you need to do is create service proxy on button click.
like

```
var proxy = new ServiceProxy();
```

where ServiceProxy is your proxy class, name of class is name you passed when added reference

```
proxy.registerToTeam(your values here, better DTO object)
```

I will suggest you

1. use MVVM concept, having viewmodel defined for the view
2. userDetails DTO object which will bind to the textboxes and other
       stuff
3. use ICommand interface for command.

all above should make your code clear.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't call web service method this way :

```
KejriwalService.aapSoapClient myclient = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
myclient.registerToTeamCompleted += 
                    new EventHandler<KejriwalService.registerToTeamCompletedEventArgs>(myclient_gregisterToTeamCompleted);
myclient.registerToTeamAsync(name.Text, street_Address.Text
                        , city_address.Text, zip_code.Text
                        , email_address.Text, phone_no.Text
                        , age.Text, gender.Text
                        );
```

Comment: I am getting a lots of errors. I am posting the complete code along with the xaml. Please see if u can fix the issue

Comment: the code above doesn't meant to be copy-paste-run ready. Change `street_Address.Text`, `city_address.Text`, and so forth with your TextBox name. If you still have errors after that, please post the error messages

Comment: error is it cannot find definition for registertoteam. I have events like registertoteamcompleted and registertoteamasync

Comment: moreover for gender i have given radio button. so how do i send the value for it?

Comment: can u plz help me out. As a new c#, windows phone developer i m finding it difficult.